# create two dataframes from original based on presence or absence of values in a row with python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Input

```
    group   treatment
0   111 lot1
1   111 lot2
2   111 lot3
3   111 lot4
4   111 other
5   111 unknown
6   111 other 
7   111 unknown
8   111 another
9   222 other
10  222 unknown
11  222 unknown
12  222 other
13  333 lot1
14  333 lot2
15  333 lot3
16  333 lot4
17  333 other
18  333 unknown
19  444 other
20  444 unknown
21  444 unknown
22  444 other
```

There are two groups in this input: the first group (111 and 333) has lot1,2,3,4, 'other' and 'unknown' in the treatment column, while the other group (222 and 444) has only 'other' and 'unknown'. I want to split them into two dataframes so that each dataframe captures one of these groups:

Output
df1=

```
group   treatment
111 lot1
111 lot2
111 lot3
111 lot4
111 other
111 unknown
111 other 
111 unknown
111 another
333 lot1
333 lot2
333 lot3
333 lot4
333 other
333 unknown
```

df2=

```
group   treatment
222 other
222 unknown
222 unknown
222 other
444 other
444 unknown
444 unknown
444 other
```

Basically, I want to split the original into two dataframes, df1 will contain groups that have lot1,2,3,4,other,unknown in the treatment column, while df2 will contain only those groups that only have other,unknown in the treatment column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
needed_values = set(['other', 'unknown'])

df_1_data = list()
df_2_data = list()

groups = df.groupby('group')
for name, df_g in groups:
    t = df_g.to_dict(orient='records')
    unique_values = set(df_g['treatment'].unique())
    if unique_values == needed_values:
        df_2_data += t
    else:
        df_1_data += t

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df_1_data)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_2_data)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is the original input has thousands of these  needed to be split into two groups

Comment: What is the rule to split your `group` column? The data in your question might be fake. Therefore, you have to provide your real data, or you have to find the pattern on your own.

Comment: Basically, I want to split the original into two dataframes, df1 will contain groups that have lot1,2,3,4,other,unknown in the treatment column, while df2 will contain only those groups that only have 'other', and 'unknown' in the treatment column